# How to process two entities with the same value in API.ai

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dialogflow-es

I am using `API.ai` as NLP input interface, when i am typing 
"I am having rice"
It should process two entities `fooditem` and `foodtiming` 
I have created these two entities and also mapped `rice` with these two entites,
but while typing this command it takes only one entity value

Comment: You can't do that